# Android SDK manager is not properly installed in VS2022 Preview 4

Tags: android, sdk, visual-studio-2022

I have installed Visual Studio 2022 Preview 4, when I try to open the Android SDK manger from Tools > Android -> Android SDK Manager. I faced the below error

[image]

Could you please suggest how to fix this issue.